# Ignore or replace dependencies' imports when bundling with Rollup

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollupjs

I'm bundling a JS library using Rollup. This lib has a dependency on [@tensorflow/tfjs-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-core).

On tfjs's code, there's a function that fetches a URL. If it's in the browser environment, it uses the global `fetch` function; if it's not, it tries to import `node-fetch`.

Something among these lines:

```
fetch(path: string, requestInits?: RequestInit): Promise<Response> {
  if (env().global.fetch != null) {
    return env().global.fetch(path, requestInits);
  }

  if (systemFetch == null) {
    systemFetch = require('node-fetch');
  }

  return systemFetch(path, requestInits);
}
```

My library is made to run in the browser, so it always uses the global `fetch` function. However, Rollup still bundles `node-fetch`'s require in my lib's assets.

It should not be an issue, but some consumers are reporting errors when using the library in a React project that uses webpack:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/[my lib]/index.js
> Cannot find module: 'node-fetch'. Make sure this package is installed.
>
> You can install this package by running: npm install node-fetch.

**Question is:** is there some way I can tell Rollup not no bundle this?

I thought about replacing the `require('node-fetch')` by `undefined` after the bundle is generated, but it feels like a dirty hack. Any other sugestions?

PS: I believe marking `node-fetch` as `external` on consumer projects would fix the issue, but since I do not use `node-fetch` in my lib, it would be nice to remove it from final output.

Comment: A good starting point would be to look at package.json for that module. it has ["browser"](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/master/tfjs-core/package.json#L85) property which disables installation of `node-fetch`

Comment: have you considered module aliasing in Rollup?

Comment: Also can you share your rollup config + package.json ?

Answer (score 1):

Other package managers can include or exclude files based on the environment, `test`, `development`, `production`, etc.

There is any number of ways of implementing this, even going so far as

```
# Makefile

ENVIRONMENT ?= test

ROLLUP = $(which rollup)

ENVSUBST = $(which envsubst)

rollup.config.js: src/$(ENVIRONMENT)
    ${ENVSUBST} < $@ > $^
    ${ROLLUP} $^ -o $(ENVIRONMENT).js
```

If you created files named after your environments, you could compile them using

```sh
make -e environment=browser
```

I don't expect my code to work, only to express ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There is this [loc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/d26095398bbe175cb3b3a32ed845e38b1b66b74a/tfjs/rollup.config.js#L70) which is used to exclude node-fetch from the bundle. You could consider a similar approach in your rollup configuration. (I think) If you add that, node-fetch will/should not be a part of your minified library.